# Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be sets such that $A\subseteq C$, $B\subseteq C$ and $(C\setminus A)$ $\subseteq$ $B$. Then $A$ $\cup$ $B$ $=$ $C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**My attempt**

Claim: Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be sets such that $A$ $\subseteq$ $C$, $B$ $\subseteq$ $C$ and $(C\setminus$$A$) $\subseteq$ $B$. Then $A$ $\cup$ $B$ $=$ $C$.

Proof. ($\subseteq$) Suppose $x$ $\in$ $A$ $\cup$ $B$. Then $x$ $\in$ $A$ or $x$ $\in$ $B$.

$\cdot$ Case 1 ($x$ $\in$ $A$): Because $A$ $\subseteq$ $C$, it follows that $x$ $\in$ $C$.

$\cdot$ Case 2 ($x$ $\notin$ $A$): Since $x$ $\in$ $A$ $\cup$ $B$, we have $x$ $\in$ $B$. As $B$ $\subseteq$ $C$ $\Rightarrow$ $x$ $\in$ $C$.

In either case, $x$ $\in$ $C$. Because $x$ is an arbitrarily chosen element of $A$ $\cup$ $B$, we have $A$ $\cup$ $B$ $\subseteq$ $C$.

($\supseteq$) Suppose $x$ $\in$ $C$. Then either $x$ $\in$ $A$, or $x$ $\notin$ $A$.

$\cdot$ Case 1 ($x$ $\in$ $A$): If $x$ $\in$ $A$, then $x$ $\in$ $A$ $\cup$ $B$.

$\cdot$ Case 2 ($x$$\notin$ $A$): Since ($C$$\setminus$$A$) $\subseteq$ $B$, we have $x$ $\in$ $B$ $\Rightarrow$ $x$ $\in$ $A$ $\cup$ $B$.

In either case, $x$ $\in$ $A$ $\cup$ $B$. Since $x$ is an arbitrarily chosen element of $C$, we have $C$ $\subseteq$ $A$ $\cup$ $B$.

Therefore, $A$ $\cup$ $B$ $=$ $C$, as claimed.

Comment: Yes, this all seems correct.

Comment: It's correct and good.  But if you are going into this much detail and exposition (which is a *good* thing at this level) on $\supseteq$ Case 2: I'd suggest adding an exposition:  Case 2($x\not \in A)$ ... <add>As $x \in C$ and $x\not \in A$ then $x \in C\setminus A$....<endadd>.  .... Yeah, I know it is obvious and any reader ought to be able to automatically fill it in but at this level of clear exposition it should be spelled out.